# Frequency of trajectories by ID

Tags: r, dplyr, count, sum, duplicates

I know there are hundreds of questions with answers on how to count but I cannot really find a solution for my problem and I ran out of ideas.

I have a set of trajectories, e.g. longitudinal data, with a value for each period. I need to get the count of specific trajectories if **all** the values are the same by id.

```
mydata <- data.frame(id=rep(1:8, each = 4), time=rep(1:4, 8),
                                       value=c(1,1,2,2,1,2,3,4,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,3,1,3,4,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2))



desired_output <- data.frame(id=rep(c("1_3_8","2_6","4","5","7"),each = 4), time=rep(1:4, 5),
                         value=c(1,1,2,2,   1,2,3,4,         1,2,2,3,    1,3,4,4,      1,2,2,2),
                         weight = c(3,3,3,3,  2,2,2,2, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1  ))
```

As you can see they are only summed up when **all** the trajectory is the same for 2 individuals.
I would really appreciate some help, the output does not need to be in the format here presented, maybe there's something more efficient or easy to work with?
SO make magic!

Answer (score 0):

I have written out how I would do it in a reprex below however I aprreciate there are a large number of steps to my solution part of this is to get it into the desired output form. (It is possible the solution is in the form you need in a subset of these lines so I would suggest you run the code one line at a time to check).

1. Rearrange rows so that the times are the columns and so a full trajectory takes up only one row (done using `pivot_wider()`)
2. Combine the trajectory into a character string (i.e. each trajectory is uniquely defined). I used the `unite()` function to do this
3. Group by the trajectory and count the number of each trajectory. I used `group_by()` and n() to do this
4. Nest the data frames to collect together the IDs (using `nest`)
5. Convert the list of matching trajectories to a string of the ids.
6. Use mutates and unnestings to convert the data back to the long format (using `unnest` and string manipulation functions.
7. Add back in times as the trajectories remained in order for each unique trajectory

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydata <- data.frame(id=rep(1:8, each = 4), time=rep(1:4, 8),
                     value=c(1,1,2,2,1,2,3,4,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,3,1,3,4,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2))

mydata %>% 
    pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = time, values_from = value) %>% 
    unite(col = trajectory, -id, sep = "/") %>% 
    group_by(trajectory) %>%
    mutate(weight = n()) %>% 
    nest(id) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate(ids = map_chr(data, ~paste(.x$id, collapse = "_"))) %>%
    mutate(trajectories  = str_split(trajectory, "/")) %>% 
    select(ids, trajectories, weight) %>% 
    unnest(c(trajectories)) %>% 
    group_by(ids) %>% 
    mutate(times = 1:length(trajectories))
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#> # Groups:   ids [5]
#>    ids   trajectories weight times
#>    <chr> <chr>         <int> <int>
#>  1 1_3_8 1                 3     1
#>  2 1_3_8 1                 3     2
#>  3 1_3_8 2                 3     3
#>  4 1_3_8 2                 3     4
#>  5 2_6   1                 2     1
#>  6 2_6   2                 2     2
#>  7 2_6   3                 2     3
#>  8 2_6   4                 2     4
#>  9 4     1                 1     1
#> 10 4     2                 1     2
#> 11 4     2                 1     3
#> 12 4     3                 1     4
#> 13 5     1                 1     1
#> 14 5     3                 1     2
#> 15 5     4                 1     3
#> 16 5     4                 1     4
#> 17 7     1                 1     1
#> 18 7     2                 1     2
#> 19 7     2                 1     3
#> 20 7     2                 1     4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>